# Javascript alternative to :hover; using loops for every div child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been using the following code (or something like it) for quite some time to display information on a given post:

Html:

```
<div class="main">
<div class="info">
    <div>Words</div>
    <div>Words</div>
     <div>Words</div>
     <div>Words</div>
     <div>Words</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.main {
    position:relative;
    background-color:#aaa;
    margin:150px auto 0 auto;
    width:50%;
    height:300px;
}

.info {
    background-color:#ccc;
    position:absolute;
    width:30%;
    top:0;
    left:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.info div {
     position:relative;
     right:100%;
    opacity:0;
    margin:10px 7px 20px 7px;
    transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
}
.main:hover .info div:nth-child(1){
    transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
    right:0;
    opacity:1;
}
.main:hover .info div:nth-child(2){
    transition:all .5s ease-in-out .1s;
    right:0;
    opacity:1;
}
.main:hover .info div:nth-child(3){
    transition:all .5s ease-in-out .2s;
    right:0;
    opacity:1;
}
.main:hover .info div:nth-child(4){
    transition:all .5s ease-in-out .3s;
    right:0;
    opacity:1;
}
.main:hover .info div:nth-child(n + 4){
    transition:all .5s ease-in-out .4s;
    right:0;
    opacity:1;
}
```

I'm trying find a solution that works no matter how many divs within the info div there are; for example, if there were 50 divs, I would like each div to come out .1s later than the last. In the example given, there are a set number of divs within .info, but in the situation I hope to apply this to there will be an unknown number of divs- it could be 50, it could be none.

So, if possible, I was hoping if there was a Javascript solution that could loop through a varying amount of divs, replacing my current CSS transition code.

Comment: `:hover requires the object effected to be a child` what? What do you mean by that?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what exactly you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't know what you mean by saying that using :hover the elements need to be child nodes, but anyways using your code and based on what you want to do i belive this is actually a pretty good solution

## CSS

```
.main:hover .info div{
    transition-property:all;
    transition-timing-function:ease-in-out;
    transition-duration:.5s;
    right:0;
    opacity:1;
}
```

then after your posts are added you do

## JS

```
$('.main:hover .info div').css('transition-delay',function(index){
     if(index>=4){
         return '.4s'
     }
     else{
       return index*0.1+'s'
    }


})
```

this relieves the load of animating out of your js and makes your code to perform better if you can relay the animations and styles to css always do so instead of using animations.

how ever if you eould like to do it completeley in JS you can do something like

```
    $('baseElement').on('mouseenter','.main',function(event){
           $($(event.target).find('.info div)).animate({});//perform what ever animation you want here
    });

    $('baseElement').on('mouseleave','.main',function(event){
          $($(event.target).find('.info div)).animate({});//return to the initial state
    })
```

how ever i don't recommend this since it involves not only more processing and animations on a non optimal way, but also tides your DOM manipulation to your javascript events what will eventually make it harder to debug if you project grows

Answer (score 1):

I would just set the CSS `transition` properties of all of these `div`s in JavaScript when the document loads:

```
var wordDivs;
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() { //When the document loads...
    //Get all of the div elements (and some text, because this is .childNodes [I could use .children here, but I don't think Safari supports that]).
    wordDivs = document.getElementById("main").childNodes[1].childNodes;
    //We loop through wordDivs...
    for (var i = 0; i < wordDivs.length; i++) {
        if (wordDivs[i] instanceof HTMLDivElement) { //If the element we're checking is a div...
            //We set its CSS transition property.
            wordDivs[i].style.transition = "all .5s ease-in-out ."+(i-1)/2+"s";
        }
    }
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NobleMushtak/uv69C/

Answer (score 1):

Try this pen: http://codepen.io/Leth0_/pen/lhwfE

```
$(".main").mouseover(function(){
  var x = 200;
  $(".info").children().each(function(){    
    $(this).delay(x).fadeIn(x).animate({"right":"0%"},"slow").css({opacity:1});    
  x = x + 200;
  });
});
$(".main").mouseout(function(){
  var x = 200;
  $(".info").children().each(function(){    
    $(this).delay(x).animate({"right":"100%"},"slow").fadeOut(x+200)    
  x = x + 200;
  });
});
```

Try this pen out, I believe it does what you want. It doesn't work great when going in and out the div multiple times but I'll fix that if I can. I'll edit when I have.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would keep it CSS. What you're accomplishing is purely presentational. This is perfect for CSS. In addition, you don't have a JS dependency for animation.

As for the CSS, you could clean it up to make it more maintainable. For example:

```
.main {
    position:relative;
    background-color:#aaa;
    margin:150px auto 0 auto;
    width:50%;
    height:300px;
}

.info {
    background-color:#ccc;
    position:absolute;
    width:30%;
    top:0;
    left:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.info div {
    position:relative;
    right:100%;
    opacity:0;
    margin:10px 7px 20px 7px;
    transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
}
.main:hover .info div {
    right: 0;
    opacity: 1;
}
.main:hover .info div:nth-child(2){
    transition-delay: .1s;
}
.main:hover .info div:nth-child(3){
    transition-delay: .2s;
}
.main:hover .info div:nth-child(4){
    transition-delay: .3s;
}
.main:hover .info div:nth-child(n + 4){
    transition-delay: .4s;
}
```

However, if the lines of code are too much, using JS to manipulate the `transition-delay` property directly is an alternative.